# Determine object moving towards or away from given latitude-longitude points

Tags: java, google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I need to determine whether an object (car, for example) is moving towards the given latitude-longitude co-ordinates or moving away from it.
Is there any API as such to determine or any formula that can help in this?
I need this to implement in my Java based web-application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute the distance between your object and your given coordinates. If current_distance < previous_distance the object is approaching, otherwise the object is moving away.

Comment: May be. In terms of something like circular route?